# Mocking collaborators in Angular controller and service Jasmine tests

Tags: angularjs

I have been writing some Jasmine unit tests in Angular. In the first example I'm testing a controller.

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, Config){
    ...
});
```

I have a configuration service (Config) that keeps configuration from the database and is injected into my controller. As this is a unit test, I want to mock out that configuration service altogether, rather than allowing execution to pass through it and using $httpBackend. Examples I found taught me about a $controller function I can use like this, in order to get an instance of my controller with my mocks injected in place of the usual collaborator:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope){
  var scope = $rootScope.$new();
  var configMock = { 
    theOnlyPropertyMyControllerNeeds: 'value'
  };
  ctrl = $controller('MyCtrl', {
            $scope:scope, 
            Config: configMock
        });
}));
```

But I also have other services that use the Config service. To help unit test them, I assumed there would be a similar $service function I could use to instantiate a service with whatever mocks I want to provide. There isn't. I tried $injector.get, but it doesn't seem to let me pass in my mocks. After searching for a while, the best I could come up with in order to instantiate a service in isolation (avoid instantiating its collaborators) is this:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  mockConfig = { 
    thePropertyMyServiceUses: 'value'
  };

  module(function($provide) {
    $provide.value('Config', mockConfig);
  });

  inject(function($injector) {
    myService = $injector.get('MyService');
  });
});
```

Is this the right way? It seems to be overriding the entire application's definition of the Config service, which seems maybe like overkill.

Is it the only way? Why is there no $service helper method?

Comment: You shouldn't mock your collaborators.

Answer (score 1):

For unit testing, it is common that you override a service for the sake of testing.  However, you can use $provide to override an existing service instead of using inject, as long as you load the application before hand.

Assuming that you created `Config` using something like:

```
angular.moduel('...', [...]).factory('Config', function (...) {...});
```

If so, try this:

```
...
beforeEach(module("<Name of you App>"));

beforeEach(
    module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.factory('Config', function (...) {...});
    });
);
...
```

After that, when you initialise your controller, it will get the mocked `Config`.